# How to use json in register class and log in class

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a registration page and I want to upload data from my registration page to the server and after Login, I want to get the data which I submit at the time of registration.

This is my Register class :

```
public void requestData() {

 if (generalUtilities.isConnected()) {        

                StringRequest requestRegister = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalData.SIGNUP,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                try {       
                                    final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    if (jObject.getString("status").equals("1")) {
                                        Log.e("baba", "baba22");
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = jObject.getJSONObject("data");

                                        edtMailId.setText(jsonObject.getString("Email"));        

                                        String email = jsonObject.getString("Email");
                                        String password = jsonObject.getString("Password");

                                        Log.e("email", email);
                                        Log.e("password", password);

                                        b = new Bundle();
                                        b.putString("EMAIL", email);
                                        b.putString("PASSWORD", password);


                                    } else {

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                                Log.e("error", "" + volleyError.getMessage());
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("FirstName", edtFirstName.getText().toString().trim());
                        params.put("LastName", edtLastName.getText().toString().trim());
                        params.put("Email", edtMailId.getText().toString().trim());
                        params.put("Password", edtPassword.getText().toString().trim());
                        params.put("DOB", edtDob.getText().toString().trim());
                        params.put("Gender", "" + RadioButtonMale.isChecked());
                        params.put("HomePhone", edtHomePhone.getText().toString().trim());
                        params.put("WorkPhone", edtWorkPhone.getText().toString().trim());      

                        return params;
                    }
                };

                RequestQueue registerqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

                registerqueue.add(requestRegister);

            } else {

                generalUtilities.showAlertDialog("Hey User", "Please Connect To The Internet", getContext());        
            }
        }
```

This is My login class :

```
 public void requestData() {

    if (generalUtilities.isNetworkAvailable()) {

        // mProgressDialog.show();
        StringRequest requestLogin = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalData.LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            Log.e("login", response);
                            final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jObject.getString("status").equals("1")) {

                                // mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                JSONObject jsonObject = jObject.getJSONObject("data");
                                Email = jsonObject.getString("Email");
                                Password = jsonObject.getString("Password");
                                Log.e("email", Email);
                                Log.e("password", Password);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data not getting from the server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.e("error", "" + volleyError.getMessage());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Email","aman");
                params.put("Password","123345");

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue loginqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        loginqueue.add(requestLogin);
    } else {
        generalUtilities.showAlertDialog("Hey User", "Please Connect to the Internet", getContext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. import Gson.jar on your project
2. Use new Gson().toJson(Object o) will return a String Object to you! That's what you need! 
   Good luck!

Comment: i am using volley.but i am confuse in that how i submit the data on the server and in login activity how can i retrieve it.

Comment: Sorry , what your meaning is that printing the data when you submit ?

Comment: I have a registration page and I want to upload data from my registration page to the server and after Login, I want to get the data which I submit at the time of registration.

Comment: Just new an Object to save your upload data !

Answer (score 0):

What you need is getting an Object to save your uploaded data;

When you login, just use Intent.putExtra(Data)!

I hope it can help you !

public class SumitData{

private String FristName;

private String LastName;

private String Email;

...
}

SumitData sumitdata;

public void requestData() {

sumitdata = new SumitData();`enter code here`
   ...

sumitdata.setFirstName(edtFirstName.getText().toString().trim());

sumitdata.setLastName(edtLastName.getText().toString().trim());

...

Map params = new HashMap();

params.put("FirstName", sumitdata.getFirstName());

params.put("LastName", sumitdata.getSecondName());

...

return params;

...}

Comment: nothing,it's a easy work ! Just add setting and getting method,and then put your upload data in it ! If it doesnot work , debug to found the problem ! o(∩_∩)o